# CSS: Different vertical alignments for a single <td>

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment, center

I'm trying to create a table containing images in a gallery along with their names right below them. I'd like to center the images vertically in each column, and have the names aligned at the bottom of the `<td>`, but I can't seem to get it to work. This is my code so far:

```
table.gallery {
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
table.gallery td {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    width:33%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
table.gallery td img{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
table.gallery td span.desc {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

And my Php code to display the table:

```
<table border="0" class="gallery"><tr>
<?php
    $curtd = -1;
    foreach ($img_arr as $item) {
        $curtd++;
        if ($curtd >= 3){
            echo '</tr><tr>';
            $curtd = 0;
        }
        echo '<td><center><a href="'.$item['link'].'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$item['thumb'].'" /></a></center>
                <span class="desc"><a href="'.$item['link'].'" target="_blank">'.$item['title'].'</a></span></td>';
    }
?>
</tr></table>
```

My images appear to center vertically with no problems, but the names still appear directly under the images, rather than at the bottom of the cell. How can I fix this?

EDIT: Here's the HTML generated by the Php code (removed URLs and stuff just for the sake of saving space):

```
<table border="0" class="gallery"><tr>
<td>
    <center><a href="[link]" target="_blank"><img src="[URL]" /></a></center>
    <span class="desc"><a href="[link]" target="_blank">[name]</a></span>
</td>
<td>
    <center><a href="[link]" target="_blank"><img src="[URL]" /></a></center>
    <span class="desc"><a href="[link]" target="_blank">[name]</a></span>
</td>
<td>
    <center><a href="[link]" target="_blank"><img src="[URL]" /></a></center>
    <span class="desc"><a href="[link]" target="_blank">[name]</a></span>
</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>
    <center><a href="[link]" target="_blank"><img src="[URL]" /></a></center>
    <span class="desc"><a href="[link]" target="_blank">[name]</a></span>
</td>
<td>
    <center><a href="[link]" target="_blank"><img src="[URL]" /></a></center>
    <span class="desc"><a href="[link]" target="_blank">[name]</a></span>
</td>
<td>
    <center><a href="[link]" target="_blank"><img src="[URL]" /></a></center>
    <span class="desc"><a href="[link]" target="_blank">[name]</a></span>
</td>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: TABLES are for data, not layouts.

Comment: Please post your generated HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: Edited with the HTML output. And I generally avoid tables, but they seemed to work best in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

Use two tr tags and in first  - image - , next  - name -

Comment: That does seem to work. The problem with though, is then I'd only have one picture appear per row, unless I figure out a workaround (which I could probably do but would prefer not to if I can avoid it).